# Get rid of a typo in vim propagated with supertab

Tags: vim

Occasionally I type in some identifier incorrectly, but don't notice and then repeat the exact same mistake by using SuperTab extension. In Sublime, I would use multi-cursor to quickly edit all the instances of this typo. Typing `:%s/Identfier/Identifier/g` takes longer; how can I do the same quicker and more effectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are following ways I can think of to save some typing:

#### with :s cmd

on one `Identfier`, press `*`, then `:%s//Identifier/g`

#### with `:s` and `<c-r><c-w>`

on one `Identfier`, press `*`, then `:%s//<c-r><c-w>/g` (after `<c-r><c-w>` do correction)

#### with (recursive) macro :

on one `Identfier` press `*`, then press `qqffii<esc>n@qq` then `@q`

#### with (recursive) macro and vim's spell checking feature :

`:set spell` to enable spellchecking then:

on one `Identfier` press `*`, then press `qq1z=n@qq` then `@q`

Comment: +1 Expanding on your idea a bit, OP could use `g*` and instead of typing `Identifier` he could then use `<c-r>\\` to prefil with the word to replace. Depending on the length and position to adjust, it might save keystrokes *(but it burns brain cycles)*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I added the `<c-r><c-w>` to prefill replacement. thx.

Comment: Lets make it five ways: Search via `/Identfier/` or `*`, then change the word via `cgn`. Then press `.` to repeat the change until done

Answer (score 2):

If it's fewer keystrokes you're after, with the cursor on the offending word, press `*` followed by `:%s//Identifier/g`.

Short of writing a special function to prompt for the replacement then replace all occurrences of the word under the cursor, I can't think of a more succinct way to do this.